# automount sshfs with autofs and sshpass

Tags: ssh, sshfs, autofs, sshpass

I want to mount partitions from a remote NAS that doesn't support login with a certificate.

I created or edited the following files:

- `/etc/ssh/sshpass.232` with ssh password
- `/etc/ssh/sshpass.232.sh` with execute permissions and the following content:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  sshpass -f /etc/ssh/sshpass.232 ssh $*
  ```
- `/etc/auto.master` with the following content:

  ```
  /mnt/232       /etc/auto.232  uid=0,gid=0,--ghost
  ```
- `/etc/auto.232` with the following content:

  ```
  serverroot -fstype=fuse,allow_other,follow_symlinks,ssh_command='/etc/ssh/sshpass.232.sh'  :sshfs\#user@sshfs_server_ip\:/mount_path
  ```

Then I restarted the autofs service:

```
sudo systemctl restart autofs.service
```

I tried to run `ls /mnt` and saw that `/mnt/232` appears in the `/mnt` folder. Then I ran `ls` in `/mnt/232/` and I saw that the the folder `/mnt/232/serverroot` is there. But when I try `ls /mnt/232/serverroot`, it says:

```
ls: cannot access '/mnt/232/serverroot/': No such file or directory
```

If I do it manually with mount:

```
sshfs -o allow_other,follow_symlinks,ssh_command='/etc/ssh/sshpass.232.sh' user@sshfs_server_ip:/mount_path /mnt/232/serverroot
```

It works flawlessly. Also, if I do a cifs config with autofs, it works fine.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try removing the single quotes from `/etc/auto.232`, as you dont need them and in your manual mount they are effectively removed by the shell.

Comment: At 1st, I wanted to remove the single quotes, then, while troubleshooting, effectively forgot about it. I've removed them now and it worked! Thanx!